# Espresso tested view is below dialog and therefore Espresso can't find it

Tags: android, dialog, android-espresso

I want to verify that there's a view on the UI that mathces some arbitary text. Therefore I'm using:

`onView(withId(R.id.my_view_id)).check(matches(withText("my text")));`

The problem is though that depending on the battery level of the device there might be a dialog saying that the battery level is low.

The dialog that will be shown is a normal `AlertDialog`.

My test runs fine if I don't show the dialog, the moment I'll show it the above espresso statement fails.

How can I tell espresso that I don't care about the dialog and just want to find the view? As Espresso is trying to find the view `R.id.my_view_id` on the `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do that. From [RootViewPicker.java](https://github.com/bootstraponline/android-test-kit/blob/master/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/base/RootViewPicker.java):

```
// when an android.app.dialog is shown
// - again, this is getting all the users attention, so it gets the test attention
// too.
```

I'd recommend mocking your battery dialog logic so you can control if it is shown or not during test. See http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html and https://gum.co/AndroidTestSharedPref for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see also another solution than chiuki.

There's `@Before` annotation which you may add to method like

```
@Before
public void checkIfAlertDialogIsShown() {
   //your code
}
```

This method would run before every `Espresso` test. So you can check if this battery-low situation happens.

Unfortunately, Espresso can't catch `AlertDialog` or system notifications. For this purpose you can use another great Google's tool called `uiautomater`. It works good with Espresso, so you may use both of them.

So in @Before annotated method you would check using `uiatomater` framework if it happens. If true, than you would close this Dialog.

Check these links to learn more about `uiatomator`:

- http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html
- https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator
- https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/uiautomator/index.html

Hope it help